# how to ensure quartz scheduler is running always

Tags: service, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, job-scheduling, delayed-execution

My entire application's state depends on the quartz scheduler.
I am running a daily job which runs every 24 hours and updates the application state based on the logic written in job's execution function.

While testing, I found that sometimes when the system gets heavily loaded, scheduler do not work and the state does not change.

When I was running scheduler for every second and keeps system heavily loaded I was able to reproduce this case frequently.

Is there any way to ensure that quartz scheduler is running always?